# Issues calling draw functions in drawRect(CGRect) in Xcode playground

Tags: ios, xcode6, swift-playground

I have setup a view in playground to test some code. I usually divide my drawing code into sections and call the different functions from within drawRect() call of UIView. In playground calling another function to draw from drawRect() seems to go to an infinite loop. Here is the code:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        aCircle()
    }


    func aCircle()
    {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100 )
        var Path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect )
        UIColor.blackColor().set()
        Path.fill()

    }

}

let testView = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300 ))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

however if I take out the aCircle() function out of the class structure and call it from the drawRect() it draws as expected but if the function call is not placed above the class declaration it give an error message in the drawRect call where aCircle() is called

```
"Use of unresolved identifier 'aCircle'
```

Any suggestions of keeping the call within the UIView class. Thanks